# Qt Type as parameter of function

Tags: c++, qt, templates, types, qt4

I am trying to build a function that takes a (qt) Type as a parameter and uses it to find children. My function looks like this:

```
template <typename QType>
void MyClass::activateElements(QWidget *widget, QType t)
{
    QList<QType *> buttons = widget->findChildren(t);
    foreach( QType *button, buttons )
    {
        buttons->setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I have also tried

```
template <typename QType>
void MyClass::activateElements(QWidget *widget, QType)
{
    QList<QType *> buttons = (* widget).findChildren<QType *>();
    foreach( QType *button, buttons )
    {
        button->setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I instantiate an object of the class that uses this function in another class. There I try to use it like this:

```
    QDoubleSpinBox x;
    object_of_my_class->activateElements(correctWidget, x);
```

At this point I get stuck because I get the following error:

`error: ‘QDoubleSpinBox::QDoubleSpinBox(const QDoubleSpinBox&)’ is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QDoubleSpinBox)`

How would I handle this problem, that QDoubleSpinBox and others are private? Have I approached how to build the function wrong or am I just using it incorrectly? Is there even a way to do it?

Comment: "_How would I handle this problem, that QDoubleSpinBox and others are private?_" The error states that **copy-constructor** of `QDoubleSpinBox` is private (i.e. it can't be copied). Pass by reference instead of passing by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't need an object of the type at all, only the type itself. In such case, specifying the template argument would be the way to go:

```
template <typename QType>
void MyClass::activateElements(QWidget *widget)
{
    QList<QType *> buttons = (* widget).findChildren<QType *>();
    foreach( QType *button, buttons )
    {
        button->setEnabled(true);
    }
}

// Usage:
object_of_my_class->activateElements<QDoubleSpinBox>(correctWidget);
```

This is how I would do it, as it expresses intent quite well.

If, however, you *really* want to enable type deduction from an existing object, pass it by reference to avoid the (forbidden) copy:

```
template <typename QType>
void MyClass::activateElements(QWidget *widget, const QType &)
{
    QList<QType *> buttons = (* widget).findChildren<QType *>();
    foreach( QType *button, buttons )
    {
        button->setEnabled(true);
    }
}

// Usage:
QDoubleSpinBox x;
object_of_my_class->activateElements(correctWidget, x);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot already! The first approach indeed seems to be the better option. I was there earlier but must have messed up the function call and then got lost.

Using that again I get "undefined reference to `void MyClass::activateElements<QDoubleSpinBox>(QWidget*)`. I have defined it as `template <typename QType>
    void activateElements(QWidget *widget);` in the header file. Is this my mistake?

Comment: @Shin Have you *defined* it there (including the body), or just *declared* it there (and put its implementation into a `.cpp` file)? Only the former can work: see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1782465).

Comment: I didn't know that function had to be defined in the `header` fie too. Did that and it is finally all working now. Thank you a lot for your help :)

Comment: @Shin Just to be crystal clear: *functions* don't have to, *function templates* do.